# using a boxplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to make a density plot out of 4000 rows (height.values), with 4 different categories (height.ind). this is the code i used.

```
library(ggplot2)
    
plom %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height.values, color=height.ind)) +
  geom_density() +
  labs(title = "height alimony")
```

I am able to get a density plot but there are a lot of lines instead of the 4 i want.

[image]

Anyone has an idea to fix it?

Comment: Please share a sample of your `plom` data, best using `dput(head(plom))`.

Comment: It seems like your data was imported incorrectly and `height.values` are not numeric values. When asking questions you should share your data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as well so we can run and test the code.

Comment: Try this: `plom %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height.values, color=factor(height.ind))) +
  geom_density() +
  labs(title = "height alimony")`